# Invoke stored procedure through DBAdapter in a non blocking way

Tags: soa-suite

I would like to understand how can invoke through BPEL a stored procedure in a non-blocking way. My concern is I have a stored procedure (in DBAdpater) that I'm invoking, but it takes so much time (around 30 minutes) and I cannot wait until this finishes.

I'm trying setting in composite application the invoke property "nonBlockingInvoke" but it doesn't work, the adapter is blocking until get respsonse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nonblockinginvoke is for use in a FLOW when you want a separate thread of execution for the Sync Invoke branch, so it doesn't block the *other* flows. FLOW is cooperative parallel - not true parallel. The Sync Invoke still blocks during the call. Read more [here](http://technology.amis.nl/2008/10/23/investigation-into-the-true-parallellism-of-the-oracle-bpel-pm-flow-activity-in-11g-technical-preview-4-on-flow-sequence-wait-and-asynchronous-calls/).

Anyway, one solution to your problem is to have a new composite that calls Async the composite that uses the DB adapter to execute the stored proc. So, your new service calls the other service async, thus it won't block - but the service calling the db adapter blocks, but at this point, your invoker is free.
It's not a bad idea to wrap db adapter calls in their own composite to decouple/isolate the true service implementation from the DB service interface - which can cahange.